# Minimising $|a+bw+cw^2|$ such that a,b,c are consecutive integers?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose we are given a expression $k=|a+bw+cw^2|$ such that $w$ is cube root of unity ($w\neq1$) such that $\{a,b,c\}$ are consecutive integers , then how can we minimise value of expression ? I was told to square the expression and then minimise so I did but 
$$k^2=a^2 +b^2w^2 +c^2w^4 +2(ab.w +bc +ac.w^2) $$ but this looks messed up , squaring does't seem to help , what can we do here?

Comment: Why didn't you use the (quite strong) hypothesis that $a,b,c$ are consecutive integers? Try to write them down as $n-1, n, n+1$ and use the fact that $w^2+w+1=0$. You will get that $k$ does not depend on $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $a=b-1$, $c=b+1$. This gives us
$$a+bw+cw^2 = (b-1) + bw + (b+1)w^2 = b\underbrace{(1+w+w^2)}_0 - 1 + w^2 = (w^2-1)$$
Hence,
$$\vert a+bw+cw^2 \vert = \vert w^2-1 \vert$$ Hence, if $a,b,c$ are consecutive integers the expression is independent of $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 0):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Let $$\displaystyle f(a,b,c) = \left|a+b\omega+c\omega^2\right|\Rightarrow f^2(a,b,c) = \left|a+b\omega+c\omega^2\right|^2 $$

$$\displaystyle = \left(a+b\omega+c\omega^2\right)\cdot\left(a+b\omega^2+c\omega\right) $$

Above we have used the fact $$\left|z\right|^2=z\cdot \bar{z}$$ and We take $$\left[f(a,b,c)\right]^2 = f^2(a,b,c).$$

So We Get $$\displaystyle f^2(a,b,c)=a^2+ab\omega+ac\omega^2+ab\omega^2+b^2\omega^3+bc\omega^4+ac\omega+bc\omega^2+c^2\omega^3$$

Now Using the fact $$1+\omega+\omega^2 = 0$$ and $$\omega^3=1$$

We Get $$\displaystyle f^2(a,b,c) = a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca=\frac{1}{2}\left[(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\right]$$

Now Given $a,b,c$ are Consecutive Integers, So Let $a=n-1\;,b=n$ and $c=n+1$

We Get $$\displaystyle f^2(a,b,c) = \frac{1}{2}\left[1^2+1^2+2^2\right]=3$$

So We get $$\displaystyle f^2(a,b,c) = 3\Rightarrow f(a,b,c) = \sqrt{3}$$.

If $a,b$ and $c$ are Distinct Integers.

Comment: Nice procedure but notice that we had to minimise expression , so second last step needs some correction.